# LWC: Unable to fetch custom field through the schema

Tags: lightning-web-components, schema, updaterecord

I have a LWC component in which I am trying to pull the metadata from the schema so I can use [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record). I've done this before for a different custom object(and it worked) but this time I am getting an error: `Error:(1, 1) FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION - Invalid reference MyObject__c.My_Field__c of type sobjectField in file myLwcComponent.js: Source`

Below I am sharing a piece of the component's code. If I comment out the last line the component saves alright.

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import MY_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/MyObject__c";
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/MyObject__c.Id';
import MY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/MyObject__c.My_Field__c";
```

Is there a permissions issue that I might be hitting? It seems like my LWC component can see the `Id` field but not the custom field I've created.

Comment: Did you check your Field Level Security settings? Does MyObject__c exist in a namespace?

Comment: Yep, I did check that first. It has no issues with `import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Risk__c.Id';` so it seems like it can see the object and id field just not my custom field. The custom field is there, I can query for it.

Comment: @sfdcfox What is really strange is that when I try to import a field, which I am importing in a different LWC, basically grabbing copy-pasting the import code from a different LWC I get the same error. Even though the other component is importing that field alright.

Comment: I asked a colleague to try and push the same code and he managed to do so successfully yet my IDE is still getting the same error. Isn't this a server generated error? I am clueless.

Comment: @Arthlete What IDE are you using for it? If you know whether the IDE you have leverages tooling API or metadata API that would be good to know as well.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I am using IntelliJ + Illuminated Cloud 2. Not using SFDX to deploy. If I had to make a guess I would say that it's probably using the metadata API to deploy but I am not sure. 

I rebuild my project and no matter what I do I am still getting the same error. Even though the file was saved by my colleague I cannot add anything to the file because I keep getting the same error for that line. Even though the line is already in Salesforce.

My colleague is also using the same setup - Mac + IJ + IC2.

Comment: Is there a profile difference between you and your colleague? Are you both administrators?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Seems like it's related to my Mac. I tried to push code from windows, using my credentials and had no problems. Still trying to figure out why the Mac is failing

Comment: Do you have duplicate files or something like that? I would jus peak at the HTTP request body going out of your MAC OSX? I suggest you also raise this @scott wells since its illuminated cloud specific.

Comment: Would you happen to have any idea how to peak at the HTTP request that is going out? Thanks, I will notify Scott.

Comment: Apparently this is a known issue with latest IlluminatedCloud: > An issue has been found with Tooling REST API-based deployment of LWC bundle files which import custom fields

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10253-illuminated-cloud-2/update/86871

Comment: @zaitsman - Thank you so much. I remember seeing an update for IC2 which I decided to postpone. After the update the issue is no longer present.

Answer (score -2):

1. You need to get the object Info at first using below

   `import { getObjectInfo  } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';`
2. then using wire decorator, pass on the object value and get the object info

   ```
   @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: YOUR_OBJECTAPINAME})
   yourOBJ;
   ```
3. Then return the fields using getter method like below and refer this fields' on template file to display(for example scenario)

   ```
   get fields()
   {
        return [this.yourOBJ.data.fields.yourfieldname.apiName];
   }
   ```

Comment: Please don’t ask for answer acceptance in your posts at SFSE. Thanks